# Does Azure support UDP Broadcast?

Tags: azure, udp

I am aware that Azure supports UDP, but does it support UDP broadcast?

I am wanting to use the Jenkins Swarm plugin, which requires UDP broadcast for new slaves to join the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woke this old thread up to add an update. Microsoft got this feedback through https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/400782-udp-endpoints and **UDP support is added** as shown below :
[Microsoft Azure VMs support UDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw48R.jpg)

Comment: UDP broadcast is not supported and the reason 's explained by Yushun Wang in here : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-azure-networking/suggestions/3741233-support-multicast-within-virtual-networks

Answer (score 1):

Since i don't use Azure myself i cannot be 100% sure, but it seems it is not supported :

> *Is UDP broadcast available in Windows Azure virtual networks?*
>
> Unfortunately, broadcasts are not supported in Windows Azure.

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/625a37c0-7b7e-423a-a076-6edd58d10117/is-udp-broadcast-available-in-windows-azure-virtual-networks?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork

> *Does Virtual Network support multicast or broadcast ?*
>
> No. We do not support multicast or broadcast.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn133803.aspx#BKMK_VNETFAQVNETConfig
  (Search for `broadcast` on the page)

Comment: Thanks! For whatever reason I was seeing UDP support but wasn't clear on UDP broadcast.